# Why my postMessage does not work on chrome and firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer, postmessage

I made two pages, page `a.html` is:

```
<script>
var popup = window.open("b.html");

popup.postMessage("hello there!", "*");

function receiveMessage(event)
{
    alert(event.data);
}
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

</script>
```

and page `b.html` is

```
<script>
function receiveMessage(event)
{
    alert(event.data);
    event.source.postMessage("hi there yourself!", "*");
}

window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
</script>
```

If I open `a.html` in ie, I can get these scripts work and `alert()` will popup a message on each of the page. However, when I load `a.html` in chrome or firefox, it will only open `b.html` in a window and the `alert()` won't be executed at all. Why?

Comment: `a.html` needs to wait for the popup to `load` before sending a `postMessage`

Comment: Change your logic so that **b.html** posts a message back to **a.html** when it is ready, then proceed.